# android studio com.android.volley.clienterror

Tags: java, android-studio

> its giving me a error that is called com.android.volley.clienterror
> whenever i press the register or login button. I imagine that the
> error could be that my android app isnt connected to my database but
> idk.................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText etName, etEmail, etPassword, etReenterPassword;
    private TextView tvStatus;
    private Button btnRegister;
    private  String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/login.register.php";
    private  String name, email, password, reenterPassword;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        etReenterPassword = findViewById(R.id.etReenterPassword);
        tvStatus = findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        name = email = password = reenterPassword = "";
    }
    public void save(View view){
        name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
        email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        reenterPassword = etReenterPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!password.equals(reenterPassword)){
            Toast.makeText(this , "Password mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(!name.equals("")&& !email.equals("") && !password.equals("")){
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equals("success")) {
                       tvStatus.setText("Successfully registered");
                       btnRegister.setClickable(false);
                    } else if (response.equals("failure")) {
                        tvStatus.setText("something went wrong!");
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                    data.put("name", name);
                    data.put("email", email);
                    data.put("password", password);
                    return data;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    }
    public void login(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind sharing the stack trace? Did you set the internet permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: Um i already fixed that error it was an "/" missing on my URL but still i have a error on my buttons because they dont do anything when i press them.

Comment: And my log cat doesnt display nothing